# A folder is going Kbs to Gb after zipping

Tags: linux, ubuntu

lh command on server then I'm seeing a size in kb, but when i tar a folder it goes to 7 or 8 Gb. I'm totally confuse. I have attach screen shot. Tar command is tar -czf xx.tar.gz xxx.ch. [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ls -lh` will not show the space used in subdirectories. Check with `du` to see how much space is really used in the objects you added to the archive.

Comment: Thanks now i have find that one folder is indeed big in the sub directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A directory is a type of file (indicated by the 'd' in front). The ls command only shows the size of the directory file and not of all the files that may be lying within the directory.
When you tar/gz the directory, all the files are combined into one archive file. That size would all the files and therefore could be much larger.
Do a

```
% ls -lR
```

(recursive) to see all the files within each directory.